# Remove application entry from switch-app menu

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, contextmenu, winforms

**What am I trying to achieve?**
I am writing a windows-form based application in C# .NET 2.0. The application should behave like this: No form should be visible; just a system tray icon is the entire application. So, I have to hide the form during startup and make a `NotifyIcon` available in the system tray with a `ContextMenuStrip` attached to it.

**What have I done so far?**
I have created a Windows application with the default form's properties `WindowState-Minimized` and `ShowInTaskbar-false`. Added a `NotifyIcon` and attached a `ContextMenuStrip` to it.

**What's happening?**
The application starts as a system tray icon and the form is hidden. So far so good. But when I am working with other applications and when I switch between other application using the Alt-Tab combination in Windows, the application icon appears in the switch-application menu; and when I select my application, the form appears.

**What's expected?**
The application should not be available in the switch-application menu; because, the form is empty and there is no functionality attached to it. All that is needed is the system-tray icon.

How to hide the application entry from the switch-application menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Hide();` call in `private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your program not to show the form at all, not even load it. Something like:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    //Instance of your application/form
    NoForm hw = new NoForm();

    Application.Run(); //remove the Form oject from this call

    }
```

Your application should work and you'll have only your NotifyIcon shown.